# Связь между radiobutton и dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Переписываю webforms приложение на asp и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            RadioButton2.Checked = false;
            DropDownList1.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (!RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            RadioButton2.Checked = true;
        }

    }
    protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            RadioButton1.Checked = false;
            DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (!RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            RadioButton1.Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

При переключение радиокнопок, выпадающий лист всегда остается активным. Что я упустил?

```
<asp:DropDownList   ID="DropDownList1"  runat="server" DataSourceID="BookStore" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name"  Height="51px" Width="300px" DataMember="DefaultView">

    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BookStore" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BookStoreConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Books] ORDER BY [Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <p>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Checked="True" GroupName="1" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="1" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton2_CheckedChanged" />

    </p>
```

Comment: ну вообще if if использовать не очень . лучше всетаки if else.  и условия лучше переписать.

Comment: это демонстрационный пример. и он не работает c else в том числе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решило проблему выставление значение true для свойства autopostback радиокнопки.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            RadioButton2.Checked = false;
            DropDownList1.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (RadioButton1.Checked == false)
        {
            RadioButton2.Checked = true;
        }

    }
    protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            RadioButton1.Checked = false;
            DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (RadioButton1.Checked == false)
        {
            RadioButton1.Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: насколько я знаю, свойство Checked у радиокнопки по умолчанию равно true, поэтому получается избыточная проверка условия.  и по-моему пример ничем,кроме этого не отличается от моего.

Comment: покажите как используете? свои функции.

Comment: да вообщем-то пока весь функционал это dropdowlist и две радиокнопки. на всякий случай добавил код и из .aspx. аналогичный код без проблем работал на обычных webforms.